# How do I extract and join data from a cell range based on a condition in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a range of cells (I2:AR2) containing different strings. I would like to select all of the cells starting with a particular set of characters (i.e. "Format:") and join them in cell H2. Sometimes "Format:" will appear once, sometimes it will appear numerous times in the range. Can I do this using a formula in H2?

i.e.:

Format: Paperback, Size: Large, Color: Green, Format: Offset, Year: 2020, ......

And I would want the output to be:

**Format: Paperback, Format: Offset**

Or better yet:

**Paperback, Offset**

Comment: What have you already tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: How does `Format: Paperback, Size: Large, Color: Green, Format: Offset, Year: 2020,` stored in the cells (I2:AR2)? Do you use commas to represent different cells? You can try Textjoin function.

Comment: maybe learn about the `FILTERXML()` formula and pop the Format tags/values from them...

Comment: Sadly, I have not tried much of use -- I've been searching online a lot and trying to familiarize myself with various functions (i.e. TEXTJOIN), but it is not obvious to me how to apply them conditionally to a range of columns. Having last used VB over 20 years ago, I thought maybe that would be easier, but I'm just too rusty and am running into what I know are stupid dead-ends (i.e. not declaring variables correctly, forgetting how to use RANGE, etc.)

As for the commas, yes I was using them to show different cells.

Comment: I can do this:

=IF((LEFT(T4,8)="Format: "), RIGHT(T4,LEN(T4)-8), "")

but I do not know how to automatically apply this to cells T4:AX4, nor do I know how to add the string results in the answer

Answer (score 0):

This is what i ended up doing. It was ugly, and i am not sure it counts as a solution, but:

the columns in question ranged from T:AX, so i made a second sheet (Sheet1), and put this formula in each of the cells in question:

```
=IF(left(Products!T1,8)="Author: ", right(Products!T1,len(Products!T1)-8),"")
```

i then inserted a new empty S column with this function in it:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,T1:AX1)
```

(in each case, i am putting T1 but it depended on the cell, obviously)

and once i was done i selected that column S, copied it, and then pasted the values back into column T on the Products sheet

Like i said, not sure if this counts as a solution -- i kept thinking i should be able to do it with a simple single formula -- but it worked

Comment: Something like `=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IFERROR(IF(FIND("Format:",T1:AX1)>0,LEFT(T1:AX1,FIND(",",T1:AX1)-1)),"")),"Format: ","")`?  Not sure if it will work though - you've tagged Excel 2010 which hasn't got TextJoin, but your comment says you tried it...

Comment: Thanks -- yes, i was using Excel 2010, but when people mentioned TEXTJOIN in a previous comment, i switched it into Google Sheets